# How do I create a page using Views and Drupal Commerce, where every listed term is a search term?

Tags: views, commerce

I am setting up a site using Drupal Commerce, for an online medicine store. I need to create a Views display page that displays around 30 product titles, (maybe chosen randomly and) arranged alphabetically. The challenge, however is that each of the displayed titles, when clicked, leads to a search results page, which then displays all products that have the title as part of their name. The display page is similar to the following link:

http://www.progressiverx.com/store/prescription-otc.php

If you will click on any of the displayed medicine names, you will see the search results page that I am talking about.

I am not sure if there is a specific module or some configuration/logic that I can use to achieve the same using Views. Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assign taxonomy terms (e.g. Flomax) to products, then display those terms in your view. Clicking on a term displays the term's page, with all its associated products.